# Iterate function over data frames in list, find match

Tags: r

I am trying to find the values in a list of data frames that match any value of another data frame.

The following works:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- list(a = c(9,8,5,7,6),
          b = c(9,5,8,7,6))

lapply(b, function(x) x %in% a)

$a
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

$b
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

In reality, though, the list does not consist of vectors, but of data frames, like this:

```
df1 <- tibble(a = c(111, 222, 333, 444, 555))

df2 <- tibble(a = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55), 
              b = c(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555),
              c = c(11111, 2222, 333, 4444, 55555),
              d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

df3 <- tibble(a = c(11, 22, 33, 44, 55), 
              b = c(11211, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555),
              c = c(11111, 2222, 333, 4444, 55555),
              d = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

l <- list(df2, df3)
```

When applying the same function, i get the following, which is absolutely not what i want:

```
lapply(l, function(x) x %in% df1$a)

[[1]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I guess it's not iterating all the values from df1$a over every value in every column of every tibble, but why not? The "333" should be found twice in the list. I also expected it to return all of the 40 values in the list, either TRUE or FALSE. I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use lapply 2 times

```
lapply(l, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) y %in% df1$a))

[[1]] 
[[1]]$a [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[[1]]$b [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[[1]]$c [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[[1]]$d [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[[2]]$a [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[[2]]$b [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[[2]]$c [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[[2]]$d [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

## answer for comment below

```
lapply(
  lapply(l, function(x) 
    lapply(x, function(y) y %in% df1$a)),
  as.data.frame)
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the format of the tibbles in the list?

Comment: sure.. use a third `lapply` ;-)  see edit above..